# Hyperlink in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

How do I add a link to an external published article in a comment?  I don't see the edit frame with the link button.  What is the syntax I can use? (I did search Meta but did not see ...!)

Comment: I swore I used to be able to use standard HTML <a href=" "> to do this, but testing it a couple times I can now not get it to work...

Comment: @SamHopkins HTML can be used in *posts* - not everything, but links in the form you specified do work: [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777) (Although I recall warnings that mixing HTML and MarkDown might lead to some problems.) Personally, I don't remember a possibility of using HTML in *comments* - I found some related feature requests, for example, this one: [Why can't we have simple HTML in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12786) It is from 2009 - so at the time, HTML in comments was not supported.

Comment: May I suggest at minimum a title and preferably a doi link if available. The publisher urls can rot more easily, and a title helps the reader (and any further maintenance in the future)

Comment: Very much seconding @DavidRoberts's [request](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5410/hyperlink-in-a-comment#comment27532_5410).  A huge chunk of my editing activity is hunting down posts with links to "here" or "this paper" … especially if such links go to non-Wayback'd personal pages, they are likely to rot and subsequently to be useless without some indication where they once pointed.

Answer (score 10):

To make a link in a comment you can use the `[text](url)` syntax. (And, of course, you can use simply a bare URL - but I assume you want something nicer. Having some description of a link is useful for the users reading the comment, too.) The same syntax is *possible* in posts. (Although in posts there are other possibilities how to use links. Moreover, when composing or editing a post, you can insert a link using the built-in editor.)

For example, the following syntax works both in a post and in comments:

`Link to a question on meta: [Hyperlink in a comment?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410) This looks probably slightly better than a bare URL: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410`

In the [first comment under this post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/27526) you can see how this looks in a comment - it looks approximately like this:

> Link to a question on meta: [Hyperlink in a comment?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410) This looks probably slightly better than a bare URL: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410

(As [pointed out by LSpice](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/27542), MO links are *usually* expanded in a post to full title - so putting just `https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410` in a post renders like this: [Hyperlink in a comment?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410). However, this is not true for external links - and in the comments the link to MO posts are not changed in this way either. Comments have some special links called [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/magic-links/info); such as `[mathoverflow.se]`, `[so]`, etc - they are expanded to a link with the full title of the site.)

---

See also:

- Help center: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/formatting) - specifically the section "Comment formatting"
- [Inline links in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37758) (Meta Stack Exchange)
- [How do you cite a reference in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3455) and other [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3455) (Mathematics Meta)
- [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) (Meta Stack Exchange) - the section "How can I format and link in comments?"

A basic information about formatting in comments is displayed after  you click on "help" when you're in the window for posting a comment. (Similar screenshot can be found [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-do-i-use-formatting-in-comments/77500#77500).)

[image: screenshot]

---

The above concerns using (inline) links in comments.
Since you have explicitly mentioned a "published article" I will add that using the [citation helper](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/citation-helper/info) (in the editor) and then copy-pasting the result in a comment will not work the same way as in a post.

For example, this works in a post, but [not in a comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/27539):

`<cite authors="Dashiell, F. K. jun.">_Dashiell, F. K. jun._, [**Isomorphism problems for the Baire classes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1974.52.29), Pac. J. Math. 52, 29-43 (1974). [ZBL0291.46021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0291.46021).</cite>`

However, simply removing the parts with `<cite...>` and `</cite>` yields a result which IMO [looks acceptable in a comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/27540).

`_Dashiell, F. K. jun._, [**Isomorphism problems for the Baire classes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1974.52.29), Pac. J. Math. 52, 29-43 (1974). [ZBL0291.46021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0291.46021).`

(I have used the format exactly the same as generated by the citation helper - of course, depending on personal preferences, I can imagine that some users might change it slightly.)

Comment: Link to a question on meta: [Hyperlink in a comment?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410) This looks probably slightly better than a bare URL: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5410

Comment: This version is not suitable in a comment: <cite authors="Dashiell, F. K. jun.">_Dashiell, F. K. jun._, [**Isomorphism problems for the Baire classes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1974.52.29), Pac. J. Math. 52, 29-43 (1974). [ZBL0291.46021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0291.46021).</cite>

Comment: But it looks fine after a very minor modification: _Dashiell, F. K. jun._, [**Isomorphism problems for the Baire classes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1974.52.29), Pac. J. Math. 52, 29-43 (1974). [ZBL0291.46021](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0291.46021).

Comment: Although one can observe the phenomenon in action [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5410/hyperlink-in-a-comment#comment27526_5411), it may be worth noting explicitly that, unlike in post bodies where the MO question text is automatically expanded—so that a bare MO or MMO link *becomes* a nice self-descriptive link (making the demonstration in the post a little confusing!)—in comment bodies no such expansion happens.